# C++ KeyboardEmulator

Tags: c++, linux, events, emulation, keyboard-events

I'm trying to code a KeyBoard Emulator for Linux, first I thought to use python to achieve it, but all the libraries were using X (and I don't want to use it). I decided to code in C++ to write in the keyboard buffer. After a few days of learning C++ and doing some research on Linux and how the input system works, I came up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <linux/input.h> 
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>

#define EV_PRESSED 1
#define EV_RELEASED 0

int Emulate(char character) 
{
    printf("Starting the keyboard buffer writer\n");


    int fd = 0;
    char *device = "/dev/input/event1"; 
    //write to buffer

    if( (fd = open(device, O_RDWR)) > 0 )
    {

        struct input_event event;
        printf("The keyboard code is: %d \n", KEY_A); 

        event.type = EV_KEY;
        event.value = EV_PRESSED;
        event.code = KEY_A;
        write(fd, &event, sizeof(struct input_event));

        event.value = EV_RELEASED;
        event.code = KEY_A;
        write(fd, &event, sizeof(struct input_event));
        close(fd);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(argv[1])/sizeof(int); i++){
        Emulate(argv[1][i]);//for each car in the argv 1 call Emulate
}
}
```

As you can see I'm writing manually KEY_A to press the a key. And I was wondering if there is a function or a way to change a char to the keycodes definded in the file /usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: What is C/C++ ?

Comment: First I wanted to code in C but then in C++ (because of the librairies) :) but yes it doesn’t make sense